# Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed! Apple Service Error -1018 while expo build:ios

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I have developed a mobile application using Expo react native.
Up until a month ago, I could build and upload to Google Play and App Store with no problems.
Now I can still build for Android normally and without any problems.
However, I can't build for iOS because I always get the Logging error
Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed!
Apple Service Error -1018.

```
expo build:ios
```

✔ **Choose the build type you would like**: › archive

Checking if there is a build in progress...

Accessing credentials for tranphuson in project tapioka

✔ **Do you have access to the Apple account that will be used for submitting this app to the App Store?** … yes

› Log in to your Apple Developer account to continue

✔ **Apple ID:** … tranphuson.devpro@gmail.com

› **The password is only used to authenticate with Apple and never stored on EAS
servers**
Learn more.

✔ **Password (for tranphuson.devpro@gmail.com):** … ************

› Saving Apple ID password to the local Keychain
Learn more.

✖ Logging in...

Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed!

Apple Service Error -1018. Could Not Complete Request. Your request could not be completed because of an error. Please try again later. Apple servers may be down right now, please try again in about 10-20 minutes

I have an Apple Developer ID and updaed the credentials both at developer.apple.com and expo.dev

Apple Distribution Certificate
Expiration Date
Nov 17, 2022 9:59 PM

Apple Provisioning Profile
Expiration Date
Nov 17, 2022 9:59 PM

Apple Push Key
Key ID
FAHRxxxxxx

I've searched for this problem for about a month, without any result.
Can someone help out me in this matter? Many thanks in advance.

[image: Logging in error screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Me and my colleague had the same issue and spent a few hours troubleshooting this issue.

Turns out the error message does not provide any useful information. We reverted expo-cli version back to ^3 and tried to build the ios application. It failed, but it provided a whole different error message than what we had earlier (the one you are displaying here).

It provided as such in the error message: "Please manually log into your Apple Developer account to review and accept the updated agreement".

You basically have to as an Account Holder go to Apple and agree to the new "Program License Agreement".

Comment: As a developer developing for Apple, you should become wary of any possible changes Apple makes as they have very strict guidelines. If there are any issues related to connecting to Apple, make sure to check their services for any changes (also if the servers are up or not). This is what I have learned from this lesson

Answer (score 1):

Just update your eas:

```
npm i -g eas-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

Well in my case I just deleted the previous build that I've done in expo. And build it again